# Animating launch screen zoom

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiimageview

**1:**

I'm trying to animate a zoom out/size change of a `UIImageView` . Below is how I want the launch screen to look and then once it's loaded to go onto my `HomeViewController`.

[image: How I want it to look]

**2:**

Because (at the moment) I'm doing the animation on the `HomeViewController` *which I know isn't the right way to do it*, the buttons on my `VC` instantly appear as the animation is happening

[image: Button problem]

**3:**

And finally, this is almost how I want it to look, but to achieve this, I've put a `UIView` which covers the buttons but not the logo and have animated it to fade *as if the buttons were fading in*.

[image: With UIView]

So how would I do the initial animation on the launch screen before loading my `HomeViewController`? I can't seem to add my `UIImageView` onto my `AppDelegate.swift` to do the animation there, many thanks!

**CODE:** (in `viewDidLoad` of `HomeViewController`)

```
let orginalY = self.imageView.center.y
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        self.imageView.center.y = orginalY - 100
    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2) {
        self.hidingView.alpha = 0
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do custom animation on launchscreen storyboard. You will have to use a `SplashViewController` before showing the `HomeViewController` and in your completion block of the animation present the `HomeViewController` in full screen.

Comment: This makes so much sense, I was so stuck trying to figure out why I couldn't find anything out about it, thank you!! So I'd make `SplashViewController` my initial `ViewController`, and then present `HomeViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot animate your LaunchScreen. Most of the apps in which you see animation actually have an intermediate controller/screen. Flow would be some thing like this.

1. Launch Screen (You can't do any thing here. OS will setup your application)
2. AnimationViewController (This is where you will do some of you initial setup and also animation)
3. HomeViewController (Rest of the flow for your application).